# Where are the Visual Studio Property Sheets saved?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, properties, propertysheet

In Visual Studio 2010, I have created and added several "project property sheets" to a project 's properties.
Is there any way to point or click on one of the property pages and find out where on my hard drive, the corresponding project property file (the file with extension .props) is saved?

Comment: View + (Other Windows) + Property Manager.  Select the property sheet, look in the Properties window.  The "Property Sheet File" property shows the full path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just repeating [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) comment as the answer so that I can mark the question as answered:

View + (Other Windows) + Property Manager. Select the property sheet, look in the Properties window. The "Property Sheet File" property shows the full path.